# Why isn't my text string updating?

Tags: android, timer

So I am trying to display the time passed since pressing a button on my app.

My code is:

```
/*This will initiate the timer*/
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        start=System.currentTimeMillis();
                        time=System.currentTimeMillis()-start;
                        currenttimedisplay.setText(Long.toString(time));
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 0, 1000);
```

The app runs but when I press the button it just shows "0.0".

The app doesn't close out.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting this, but when you set the start variable immediately before calculating the time, isn't it logical that the answer would be 0.0? Maybe move setting the start variable outside that block.

Comment: It would also be helpful to know in what class you are doing this

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
/*This will initiate the timer*/
        timer = new Timer();
        start=System.currentTimeMillis();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        time=System.currentTimeMillis()-start;
                        currenttimedisplay.setText(Long.toString(time));
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 0, 1000);
```

Comment: This was exactly it.  Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. For an explanation on why that works, see my (maybe too terse) comment to your question or @nvi9's answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the value of `start` is changed everytime the timer elapsed (`start = System.currentTimeMillis()`), so the value of `time` is always 0 (System.currentTimeMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis() should be 0 if it is called with no, or very small time difference...). So you should set the value of `start` on button press, then calculate the difference, and update text view in your timer task.